# Show current value in Html.EditorFor()

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view named EditEmployee.shtml that was generated by Visual Studios for me.  In it, there's a line that creates the text box to allow an Employee record to be modified.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Here's the controller:

```
public ActionResult EditEmployee(int id = 0)
{
    using (MVCTrainingDB db = new MVCTrainingDB())
    {
        var emp = db.Employees.Find(id);

        if (emp == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }

    }                        
}
```

This works perfectly, except that it doesn't show what the current value is for the model, instead it's just blank.  How can I modify this to set the value of the textbox to model.Name?

Comment: Are you setting the Name property value in your action method ?

Comment: @shyju I added the code for the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the object to the view

```
var emp = db.Employees.Find(id);
if (emp == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
else
{
    return View(emp );
}
```